# PHP. Get user home directory (for virtual hosting)

Tags: php, shell

I want to get home directory of current script user (nginx/www/apache etc.) in PHP.
I use

```
$output_message = shell_exec('echo ~');
var_dump($output_message);
```

It's working correctly on my local server, on Amazon instances. But it outputs only "~" on virtual hosting.

Maybe, do you have working solution for getting home directory of current user?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Was this question about Linux or... in general? I ask that since in some comments I've seen some people commenting about Microsoft Windows, and they probably would like to answer about it without downvotes. Thanks for this clarification

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I founded working solution:

```
$user = posix_getpwuid(posix_getuid())
```

This returns the array, e.g.

```
Array
(
    [name] => username
    [passwd] => ********
    [uid] => 501
    [gid] => 20
    [gecos] => Full Name
    [dir] => /home/username
    [shell] => /bin/bash
)
```

So to access user home dir, it's `$user['dir']`.

Comment: Note that this only works in Unix-like environments

Comment: Also note that you may be interested in `posix_geteuid()` (effective UID) instead of `posix_getuid()` (real UID) - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-geteuid.php

Answer (score 2):

Use `$_SERVER['HOME']` or you can try with

```php
$home = getenv("HOME");
```

Note: This requires that you execute the script via the command-line.

Comment: getenv returns FALSE. $_SERVER['HOME'] is not exists (Notice: Undefined index: HOME)

Comment: On windows you can use `$home = getenv("USERPROFILE")`.

Answer (score 1):

On most regular servers, those daemons (apache, nginx, etc.) have no real "home directory".

If you consider "virtual hosting", that wouldn't be possible, as there can only be one home directory per user, but many vhosts per daemon.

I guess what you are looking for, ist the environment variable DOCUMENT_ROOT (the root directory for the current vhost documents).

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

Comment: Note that the original questioner is running shell commands with `shell_exec` so I really think the user is interested in having the Unix/Linux HOME, to run some commands using that, and the user is probably not interested in the document root. But I agree this is still useful to clarify